# How to pass an argument into a controller method from a form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

In my User Show view:

```
<%= form_tag assign_as_student_path do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>
    <%= submit_tag "Assign as a Student", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

TeachersController (inherits from UsersController):

```
def assign_as_student
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @user.update_attributes(type: "Student")
    @user.save
    redirect_to admin_path, notice: "They are now a Student" 
end
```

routes.rb:

```
post 'assign_as_student' => 'teachers#assign_as_student'
```

Ok, this WORKS. But...

This was what I had to settle for, because I didn't know how to pass an argument into the controller method.

I wanted to write a method in the UsersController like the above one but with an argument like this (I think this would work, but haven't been able to test it):

```
def assign_as_type(type)
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @user.update_attributes(type: type)
    @user.save
    redirect_to admin_path, notice: "They are now a Student" 
end
```

This way, I would be able to just have this one method instead of having an "assign_as_student" method AND an "assign_as_teacher" method. Always good to be DRY.

So... I think the above method would work, but how would I pass the argument in from the form? Like the below form, but with something added that would pass in a string "Student" or "Teacher":

```
<%= form_tag assign_as_type_path do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Assign as a (Student/Teacher), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

(In this answer I assume you are using Rails 4+, otherwise some of my suggestions might not apply, it is good to supply this in the question.)

To pass another argument into the controller you could do:

```
<%= form_tag assign_as_type_path do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>
  <%= select_tag :type, options_for_select([ "Student", "Teacher" ]) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Assign", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

The parameter should then be accessible as `params[:type]`.

Since this is an action on a `@user`-object I think you should do like this:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: assign_as_type_path do |f[ %>
  <%= f.select :type, options_for_select([ "Student", "Teacher" ],@user.type) %>
  <%= f.submit "Assign", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

And also in your controller I think you should do like this:

(Here assuming that you changed to `form_for`)

```
def assign_as_type(type)
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(type: params[:user][:type]) # This sets attribute + saves
    redirect_to admin_path, notice: "They are now a " + @user.type
  else
    redirect_to admin_path, error: "User could not be updated."
  end    
end
```

This way, you can use model validation and if you do the redirect as in a normal update action you can also show errors in the form.

Hope this helps, if there is any questions, just ask

**Updated answer with `params`**

The way I understood params (and understand if something is wrong) is by looking at your latest request in the Server log (if you are running it locally it is where you started `rails s`).

Here you would see:

```
params: { user_id: 1, type: "Student" , commit: "Assign"}
```

and some other extra parameters.

This is a normal Ruby Hash called `params`. To get into the Ruby-language you can do the: http://tryruby.org/ tutorial

If you change it to `form_for` your params hash will look like:

```
params: { user: { id: 1, type: "Student" }, commit: "Assign" }
```

Ref:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html

Comment: Yet to try it, but it looks great. I want to fully understand what's going on before I implement it, and to do that I need to read up on params. I understand everything else that's going there. It's the 3rd line in the method I don't understand. I still don't really understand params. Any reading recommendation for that? A good explanation of params for intermediates seems to be hard to find.